# Wpf MVVM - Tabbed interface is not working as expected

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, tabcontrol

First: I am new to MVVM and WPF.

I am trying to create a little application with a tabbed user interface. Users can create products and storage locations, using a button which should open a new TabItem.

My code in the view looks like this:

```
<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Workspaces}"
        IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"
        Margin="3"
        DockPanel.Dock="Top">
  <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
          <Label Content="{Binding DisplayName}" />
       </DataTemplate>
  </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
</TabControl>
```

and the View Model is this:

```
ObservableCollection<WorkspaceViewModel> _workspaces;
    public ObservableCollection<WorkspaceViewModel> Workspaces
    {
        get
        {
            if (_workspaces == null)
            {
                _workspaces = new ObservableCollection<WorkspaceViewModel>();
            }
            return _workspaces;
        }
        set
        {
            _workspaces = value;

        }
    }
public void AddProduct(object obj)
    {
        Workspaces.Add(new ProductViewModel());
    }
```

Various other buttons add different ViewModels to the Workspaces Collection.

I have defined multiple Data Template (one for each ViewModel). Here is one:

```
<DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:ProductViewModel}">
    <vw:ProductView />
</DataTemplate>
```

The WorkspaceViewModel is this:

```
namespace Inventory.Desktop.ViewModels
{
public abstract class WorkspaceViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    #region Events and EventHandlers

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
}
```

and eg the ProductViewModel

```
namespace Inventory.Desktop.ViewModels
{
public class ProductViewModel: WorkspaceViewModel
{
    private Product _product;
    private string _displayName;


    public string DisplayName
    {
        get
        {
            if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(_displayName))
            {
                return "Neues Produkt";
            } else
            {
                return _displayName;
            }
        }
        set
        {
            _displayName = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("DisplayName");
        }
    }


    #region Public Properties

    public Product Product
    {
        get
        { 
            return _product; 
        }
        set
        {
            _product = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Product");
        }
    }

    public string Title
    {
        get
        {
            return _product.Title;
        }
        set
        {
            _product.Title = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Title");
        }
    }

    public string ScanCode
    {
        get
        {
            return _product.ScanCode;
        }
        set
        {
            _product.ScanCode = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("ScanCode");
        }
    }

    public string Manufacturer
    {
        get
        {
            return _product.Manufacturer;
        }
        set
        {
            _product.Manufacturer = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Manufacturer");
        }
    }

    public string ManufacturerNumber
    {
        get
        {
            return _product.ManufacturerNumber;
        }
        set
        {
            _product.ManufacturerNumber = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("ManufacturerNumber");
        }
    }

    public string Description
    {
        get
        {
            return _product.Description;
        }
        set
        {
            _product.Description = value;
            NotifyPropertyChanged("Description");
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Commands

    private ICommand _saveCommand;

    public ICommand SaveCommand
    {
        get
        {
            return _saveCommand;
        }
        set
        {
            _saveCommand = value;
        }
    }

    #endregion

    #region Command Executions

    public void Save(object obj)
    {

        using (var db = new InvContext())
        {
            db.Products.Attach(Product);
            db.Entry(Product).State = Product.ProductId == 0 ?
                EntityState.Added : EntityState.Modified;
            db.SaveChanges();
        }

        MessageBox.Show("Product saved: " + Product.Title);
    }

    #endregion

    #region Constructors

    public ProductViewModel()
    {
        if (_product == null)
        {
            _product = new Product();
        }

        SaveCommand = new RelayCommand(new Action<object>(Save));
    }

    #endregion


}
}
```

Here the `ProductView.xaml` view:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Inventory.Desktop.Views.ProductView"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="400" d:DesignWidth="450">
<DockPanel>
    <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Top" Orientation="Horizontal" FlowDirection="RightToLeft">
        <Button Name="SaveProductButton" Command="{Binding SaveCommand}" Content="Speichern" Margin="3" BorderThickness="0">
        </Button>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel DockPanel.Dock="Top" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Label Content="Scan Code" />
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=ScanCode}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="3" Padding="3" Height="50" TextAlignment="Right">
            <TextBox.Background>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="..\Images\Barcode32.png" AlignmentX="Left" Stretch="None" />
            </TextBox.Background>
        </TextBox>
        <Label Content="Bezeichnung" />
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Title, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="3" />
        <Label Content="Hersteller" />
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Manufacturer, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="3" />
        <Label Content="Hersteller Nummer" />
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=ManufacturerNumber, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="3" />
        <Label Content="Beschreibung / Information" />
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Description, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="3" />
    </StackPanel>

</DockPanel>
</UserControl>
```

and here the code-behind `ProductView.xaml.cs`:

```
namespace Inventory.Desktop.Views
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaktionslogik für ProductView.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class ProductView : UserControl
{

    ProductViewModel _productModel = new ProductViewModel();

    public ProductView()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        base.DataContext = _productModel;
    }
}
}
```

What's currently working:

- When I click a button, I got a new TabItem displaying the correct view and all commands work correctly.

What's not working:

- When I open a TabItem, enter some information, and then I open another TabItem with a different ViewModel, switching the focus to the new TabItem and then back to the original oen, then all entered information are gone (object is null).
- When I open a TabItem, enter some information, and then I open another TabItem with the same ViewModel, then both TabItems show the the same information.
- When I add a new TabItem, it doesn't get focus.

I am totally lost and I hope you can tell me what I am doing wrong.

Best

Stefan

Comment: seems like the problem is in your WorkspaceViewModel, can you post little info about WorkspaceViewModel?

Comment: Hi Mujahid. I edited my question and included the model

Comment: Try using UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged in your bindings with textboxes

Comment: for your problem 3 the solution by sthotakura will work

Comment: Hi Mujahid. Thank you for your suggestions. I added the UpdateSourceTrigger, but without any effect. I will add my ProductView xaml and code behind. i believe that setting the datacontext could have something to do with my Problems ? Problem 3 is now resolved thanks to skthotakura

Comment: @Stefan, I see you are instantiating `ViewModel` in the View Constructor, I don't think this is necessary, when you already have `DataTemplate`s, which can bring up an appropriate view, when a viewmodel is added via `Workspaces.Add(new ProductViewModel());`

Answer (score 1):

Have a property on your ViewModel to store the reference to current/selected tab

```
public WorkspaceViewModel SelectedTab
{
    get { return _selectedTab; }
    set
    {
        _selectedTab = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(() => SelectedTab);
    }
}
```

and bind this to `SelectedItem` property on TabControl.

```
<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Workspaces}"
        SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedTab, Mode=TwoWay}"
        Margin="3"
        DockPanel.Dock="Top">
  <TabControl.ItemTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
          <Label Content="{Binding DisplayName}" />
       </DataTemplate>
  </TabControl.ItemTemplate>
</TabControl>
```

And finally, you want to update `SelectedTab` property whenever you are adding a new tab. Modify your `AddProduct` like this:

```
    public void AddProduct(object obj)
    {
        var workspace = new ProductViewModel();
        Workspaces.Add(workspace);
        SelectedTab = workspace;
    }
```

Comment: Thank you. This resolves one of my Problems, that i now get Focus when adding a new tab.

Comment: @Stefan did you try removing `IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True"` and see if that resolves the other two problems?